# Selecting pandas DataFrame Rows if element is in tuples

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

Let's say this is my df

```
   A     B
0  a  (33,32)
1  b  (44,33)
2  a  32
3  a  (66,33)
4  b  (77,34,12)
5  c  (88,1,55)
```

where column B values are tuples
and I need to get something like df[df['B']contain 33]

```
   A     B
0  a  (33,32)
1  b  (44,33)
3  a  (66,33)
```

is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is mix numbers with tuples first convert integers to tuples:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,))
```

And then filter values in tuples like:

```
df = df[df.B.apply(lambda x: 33 in x)]
```

Or:

```
df = df[[33 in x for x in df.B]]
```

Or:

```
df = df[pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist()).eq(33).any(axis=1)]
```

---

```
print (df)
   A         B
0  a  (33, 32)
1  b  (44, 33)
3  a  (66, 33)
```

Comment: Thx @jezrael ! But i get this error:
argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: @Jeff - so there is mix tuples with integers?

Comment: @Jeff - I think `(32,)` is `(32)` ? Because one element tuple is defined with comma like `(value, )`

Comment: yes i just realised the column have int as well, actually the column is convert from another column with string values eg. '33,32', '33', .... etc. using literal_eval. Do you have any advice?

Comment: @Jeff - Ok, so first step should be `df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,))`

Comment: @Jeff - Its happens, first I think it was typo, so edited question first time ;)